# GTK Sharp Refresh / Redraw widget

Tags: combobox, refresh, gtk#

I'm trying to develop a really simple GUI with mono and GTK sharp. I have a few two combobox and I need to change the options available in the secod based on the selected item from the first one:

```
//Create window container
var mainContainer = new Table (3, 1, false);

//add form
var formContainer = new Table (1, 3, true);

//FIRST COMBOBOX
pdfSelect = new ComboBox(new string[] {"Monthly", "Monthly Offline", "Quarterly" }) { Active = 2 };
pdfSelect.Changed += new EventHandler(OnPdfSelectChanged);
formContainer.Attach (pdfSelect, 1, 2, 0, 1);

//MONTH COMBOBOX
monthSelect = new ComboBox(new string[] { "January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" }){ Active = 0 };

formContainer.Attach(monthSelect, 2, 3, 0, 1);

mainContainer.Attach(formContainer, 0, 1, 0, 1);

win.Add(mainContainer);
```

My change event is below:

```
public static void OnPdfSelectChanged(object o, EventArgs args) {
    ComboBox combo = o as ComboBox;
    if (o == null) return;
    if (combo.ActiveText.Equals("Monthly") || combo.ActiveText.Equals("Monthly Offline"))
    {
        monthSelect = new ComboBox(new string[] { "January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
            "August","September","October","November","December" }) { Active = 0 };
    }
    else
    {
        monthSelect = new ComboBox(new string[] { "January", "April", "July", "October" }) { Active = 0 };
    }
    //TODO REFRESH WINDOW
}
```

The code works but the second combobox seems to dont be updated. I guess I need to refresh the window?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work the two mean things is to call `Clear()` as fog said (+1) but after that you need to assign a cell rendertext or the new items will not be displayed:

[Gtk.ComboBox.Clear Method "Unsets all the mappings on all renderers for this combo box."](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.ComboBox/M)

```
public static void OnPdfSelectChanged(object o, EventArgs args) {
    ComboBox combo = o as ComboBox;
    if (o == null) return;
    //Set entries
    var entries = new string[] {  "January","February","March","April","May","June","July", "August","September","October","November","December" };
    if (combo.ActiveText.Equals("Quarterly"))
    {
        entries = new string[] { "January", "April", "July", "October" };
    }
    //clear previous data
    monthSelect.Clear();
    //cells data
    ListStore store = new ListStore(typeof(string));
    foreach (var item in entries) {
        store.AppendValues(item);
    }
    //assign data to combobox
    monthSelect.Model = store;
    //renderer for cells
    var cellRenderer = new CellRendererText();
    monthSelect.PackStart(cellRenderer, true);
    monthSelect.AddAttribute(cellRenderer, "text", 0);
    //set first item as active
    monthSelect.Active = 0;
}
```

Comment: If you assign a new model you don't even need Clear() (and, correct, you need to provide at least one cell renderer.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're assigning a new `Gtk.ComboBox` to the `monthSelect` variable but that doesn't automatically remove the old combobox from the window and add this new one. What you want is to clear the contents of the combobox and add the new content. Something like:

```
monthSelect.Clear();
monthSelect.AppendText("January");
monthSelect.AppendText("April");
monthSelect.AppendText("July");
monthSelect.AppendText("October");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but...

```cs
((ListStore)combobox.Model).Clear(); 
combobox.AppendText("item");
```